# Cant output batch file commands to txt file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i work as a network engineer and i would like to write some scripts to make my job more easy especially in situations where i cannot be on site and the client cannot connect to the internet so this is one script i made that would give me basic network test info

However my issue is i cant get it to output to a txt file after the script is ran, i want the user having the choice of weather to create the file or not. after i go through the prompt and click yes it will pause for a bit ( i assume its running the commands) however no file is made on my desktop where the file is stored.

At my work i am running windows 10, and at home xp but i need this to be able to run on either.

here is a copy of what i am having trouble with i have more questions but would first like to get this fixed

i have tried using >>output.txt (commands in here) i also tried command >> output.txt but either way there is no file on my desktop

```
>>output.txt (ipconfig /all ping google.com tracert google.com)
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: not sure how to post it this site keeps giving me an error

Comment: Just edit the question to copy/paste the code into it. Then, select the code and use the {} icon.

Comment: i edited the part i am having issue with, the other part is just the prior command that runs fine and displays all the information i need and then prompts the user for if they like to save it or not

Comment: The `output.txt` file will be appended to in the current working directory. My guess is that it is not your desktop directory. Before this command, `ECHO %CD%` to see what the current working directory is.

Comment: How about trying `>>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\output.txt" (ipconfig...`

Comment: so how should this look . after the user clicks yes i have "%userprofile%\desktop\output.txt" (ipconfig\all) it returns with a not reconized batch file or command error

Comment: i got it thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file will be saved to your current directory. You'd need to use `"%userprofile%\desktop\output.txt" as the file destination to put it on the desktop. You may need the quotes in case the resolution of`userprofile` contains separators.

Comment: the file is made however it is not giving me the command information

Comment: You are issuing 3 separate commands, so you need to separate each individual command with `&`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have three (3) commands here and need to tell the shell to do them all.

```
>>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\output.txt" (ipconfig /all & ping google.com & tracert google.com)
```

Alternatively, the .bat script might look like:

```
>>"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\output.txt" (
    ipconfig /all
    ping google.com
    tracert google.com
)
```